# Remove duplicates from multiple csv files and save in another directory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new to python / pandas. I've got multiple csv files in a directory. I want to remove duplicates in all the files and save new files to another directory.
Below is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

list_files = (glob.glob("directory path/*.csv"))
for file in list_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_new = df.drop_duplicates()
    df_new.to_csv(file)
```

This code runs but doesn't yield expected results. A couple of issues.

1. files are overwritten in the existing directory.
2. there is an additional index column being added which is not required.

what changes need to be done in the code to get the same set of files with the same file names without duplicate rows to another directory?

Answer (score 1):

Add `index=False` parameter to_csv method to prevent new index column;

Change path in to_csv method to prevent overwriting;

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

list_files = (glob.glob("directory path/*.csv"))
for file in list_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_new = df.drop_duplicates()
    new_filename = f'new_directory/{file}'
    df_new.to_csv(new_filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This task required for 1000+ files. new_filename should be in the format like this: "new directory path/actual file name.csv" how can I iterate this?

Comment: complexity or speed is not really issue. I just want to get the job done.

Comment: Look at the answer. 
This code snippet will save new files to new_directory/directory path/*.csv
I hope, that you can work with it

Comment: new_filename = 'f'new_directory/{file}' gives an error as it seems to be joining new directory path to old directory path where as we nee to join new directory path to filename.csv

Answer (score 1):

final code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

list_files = (glob.glob("directory path/*.csv"))
for file in list_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    df_new = df.drop_duplicates()
    new_filename = f'new_directory/{filename}'
    df_new.to_csv(new_filename, index=False)
```